# ASP.NET localization in Class Library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about localization in ASP.NET MVC.

For example, I have two ASP.NET MVC application, and sometimes there is model classes which is same for all application.

The first decision is to create Class Library, put all these classes in this library and make references on it from all ASP application.

But now I have a question, if I put models in class library, how to make localization?

Comment: What you want? Use model classes same as DAL?

Comment: What differs from localizing a class library compared to another project type? I see no differences.

Comment: You shall Use `Model` in `class Library`, if you need to use in two Projects. For Localization you need to maintain a separate `Class Library` having `Resources` files like (Resource-en-Us.resx/ Resource-fr-FR.resx) which can be referenced in all Projects.